# Организовать данные в таблице sql

Tags: структуры-данных, php, база-данных, sql

здравствуйте. подскажите как можно организовать вот такие данные в бд в таблице:

```
    Среднее образование
---------------------
Название
Город

Высшее образование
-----------------

Название
Город
```

Просто прописать имена?

```
среднее_название
среднее_город

высшее_название
высшее_город
```

А если я захочу чтобы пользователь сам мог добавлять до 5 таких полей? и чтобы данные с них записывались в бд?

Answer (score 1):

```
Здравствуйте!

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите следующее:

У вас таблица с пользователями и пользователь может указывать свое образование.
Образований может быть несколько.

Тогда может подойти такая схема:

Таблица education содержит виды образований: 
education_id - идентификатор образования
education_title - вид образования

Таблица city содержит города: 
city_id - идентификатор города
city_title - название города

Таблица user_education содержит связь между пользователем и его образованиями
user_id - идентификатор пользователя
education_id - идентификатор образования
city_id - идентификатор города
```